# The parent tag of tag 'style amp-custom' is 'form', but it can only be 'head'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

I'm trying to add Amp to my Next.js project, So I just added the below line as mentioned in the Next.js Documentation:

```
export const config = { amp: true }
```

It resulted on many errors such as the title and other similar errors like in this image:

[image: errors image]

The thing is, I cant find the source or Where is this style amp-custom is coming from, I did not add it myself, I searched in the project folder for "style amp-custom" and it did not show any results, Any advice on where to find these tags and how to trace them ?

Comment: Without seeing the page you're trying to render, it is hard to help. In general, AMP pages do not allow custom javascript directly, you'll have to do it through `<amp-script>` and web workers.  Why are you trying to enable AMP? Do you know what that means for your project?

Answer (score 0):

style amp-custom tag keeps all your CSS in it. By looking at your error, it seems you have kept style amp-custom tag inside your body instead of head.